# Overriding a blanket trait implementation in Rust

Tags: rust

For my game rules engine, I have a central trait called `Rule` that handles game callbacks. There are two types of `Rule`s: a `BaseRule` applies to any entity in the game, and a `CreatureRule` applies only to Creatures. I currently structure the code like this:

```rust
trait BaseRule<T> {
    fn on_turn_start(&self, owner: &T) {}
}

#[typetag::serde(tag = "type")]
pub trait CreatureRule: BaseRule<Creature> {
    fn on_death(&self, owner: &Creature) {}
}
```

This works fine, but is slightly annoying because you need to implement both `Rule` and `CreatureRule` for every implementation. I tried to make a blanket implementation of `BaseRule`:

```rust
impl<R: CreatureRule> BaseRule<Creature> for R {
}
```

but this introduces a conflict if I try to add a new implementation of the `BaseRule` trait, e.g. via

```rust
impl BaseRule<Creature> for BaseMeleeDamageAttack {
    fn on_turn_start(&self, owner: &Creature) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

since there can't be two implementations of the same trait. Is there a way I can provide a blanket default implementation of `BaseRule` to types that implement `CreatureRule` but still allow them to override the default implementation of the functions?

(if possible I'd prefer to avoid having generic type parameters on `CreatureRule` since Serde serialization doesn't work for traits with generic types.)

Comment: In stable Rust, essentially, no. You're asking for trait specialization.

Comment: See https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1210 and https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to manually implement it for each, but it's only one line:

```rust
impl BaseRule<Creature> for ... {}
```

Automatic implementation would require either a macro (which would make the code less readable), or impl specialization ([rust-lang/rfcs#1210](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1210) and [rust-lang/rust#31844](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844)), which would currently require nightly.